# preg_match matching pattern with asterisk (*) in it

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
preg_match('/te**ed/i', 'tested', $matches);
```

gives me the following error:

> ERROR: nothing to repeat at offset 3

What do I do to allow the pattern to actually contain `*`?

Comment: Are you trying to match `tested` with that regex?

Comment: I meant using the literal "te**ed". So I assume escaping it is gonna solve the issue :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use literal asterisks you have to escape them with backslashes. To match the literal `te**ed` you would use an expression like this:

```
preg_match('/te\*\*ed/i', 'tested', $matches); // no match (te**ed != tested)
```

But I doubt this is what you wanted. If you mean, match *any* character, you need to use `.`:

```
preg_match('/te..ed/is', 'tested', $matches); // match
```

If you really want any two lower case letter, then this expression:

```
preg_match('/te[a-z]{2}ed/i', 'tested', $matches); // match
```

Comment: I meant using the literal "te**ed". So I assume escaping it is gonna solve the issue :)

Comment: @sniper: fair enough, but recognize that `$matches` in the expression given will still be empty, whereas `preg_match('/te\*\*ed/i', 'te**ed', $matches)` would produce a non-empty result.

Comment: ahh... thats exactly what I need!! :) Is there anyway to quickly escape "te**ed" in php? Any built in function?

Comment: @sniper: You can use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to escape all regex characters.

Comment: Great! That solved it! The final regular expression I used : preg_match("/".preg_quote($search_string)."/i",$topic)

Comment: `If you really want any two lower case letter` ...nope, you are using a case insensitive flag.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a backslash before any character wil tell PHP that the character should be taken as is, not as a special regex character. So:

```
preg_match('/te\\**ed/i', 'tested', $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use asterisk-like search, you can use next function:

```
function match_string($pattern, $str)
{
  $pattern = preg_replace('/([^*])/e', 'preg_quote("$1", "/")', $pattern);
  $pattern = str_replace('*', '.*', $pattern);
  return (bool) preg_match('/^' . $pattern . '$/i', $str);
}
```

Example:

```
match_string("*world*","hello world") // returns true
match_string("world*","hello world") // returns false
match_string("*world","hello world") // returns true
match_string("world*","hello world") // returns false
match_string("*ello*w*","hello world") // returns true
match_string("*w*o*r*l*d*","hello world") // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving upon Viktor Kruglikov's answer, this is the PHP 7.3 way of doing such a thing:

```php
private function match(string $pattern, string $target): bool
{
    $pattern = preg_replace_callback('/([^*])/', function($m) {return preg_quote($m[0], '/');}, $pattern);
    $pattern = str_replace('*', '.*', $pattern);
    return (bool) preg_match('/^' . $pattern . '$/i', $target);
}
```